# Cannot display jpeg from outside asset folder in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, jpeg

This is probably a problem with my ignorance, but I am simply trying to show an image ... as per the code below.

I don't get any errors. The image exists, but does not appear in the simulator.
If I change the path string to a non-existing image I get an error, so I assume it is finding the image correctly.
What am I missing?

[image of view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLfJA.png)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var hotspotImage: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let path = "/Users/Mel/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5760868E-BC01-4021-9500-1D4C09FE5106/data/Containers/Data/Application/2E99C508-30E5-4C83-BC72-CBF141A64769/Documents/tours/22/HI2.jpg"
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
        hotspotImage = UIImageView(image: image!)
    }

}
```

Comment: You are creating the UIImageView but you aren't adding it to the view hierarchy so it won't appear on screen. HotspotImage will already be a UIImageView, so you should assign image to its image property

Comment: This was happened to my app. In Objective-C we can retrieve the path and dynamically we can show the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `hotspotImage = UIImageView(image: image!)` try `hotspotImage.image = image!`.

Comment: That worked. (thanks very much). Can you tell me what was wrong with my version?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingString("filename")
    testingImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: getImagePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call and give path for Document directory

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
       .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let fileName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
               .stringForKey("HI2.jpg") ?? defaultName
let imagePath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)!
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath )

// display the image
someImageView.image = image
```